# Emacs on Windows: `shell-command` hangs when process wants input

Tags: microsoft-windows, git, shell-command

I am using Emacs on Windows 8.

Some processes when run through shell-command will request interactive input, notably commands like `git push` (which will ask for user name and password). Sometimes I will accidentially run such commands synchronously (`shell-command` without `&`) and Emacs will just freeze. The same happened with some commands when I was using `bzr`.

After freezing, it will become impossible to resolve the issue from within Emacs – `C-g` and any other input is simply ignored – and I have to track down the executable in the task manager. This may be related to the password prompt of git, which even in Cygwin entirely ignores common signals (e.g. `C-c`).

Is there some fix for this behaviour? I can do  it for `git push` specifically with some function-advice for `shell-command`, but I'd rather find a general solution.

## Workaround

For reference: My current solution is to add an advice to `shell-command`, that adds the forgotten ampersand `&`, detecting commands by regular expression.

```
(advice-add #'shell-command :filter-args #'shell-command-git-fix-advice)
(defun shell-command-git-fix-advice (args)
  (when (and
         (not (string-match-p "&[ \t]*$" (car args)))
         (string-match-p "^git +push +" (car args)))
    (setcar args (concat (car args) "&")))
  args)
```